# Efficiently copying a String into a pre-allocated ByteBuffer as UTF-16 without any GC overhead in Java

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I have a pre-allocated ByteBuffer and need to copy a String into it, preserving the original UTF-16 format of the string. One of the key requirements is to avoid any garbage collection overhead during this process.

Here's my current implementation:

```
private static void strcpy(ByteBuffer dest, String src)
 {
     int len = src.length();

     for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
     {
         dest.putChar(src.charAt(i));
     }
 }
```

I'm curious if, under the influence of the JIT, this could be optimized into more efficient assembly code, possibly leveraging SIMD instructions. Is there any insight or optimization guidance on this aspect?

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Does it have to be preallocated? `CharBuffer.wrap()` comes to mind.

Comment: toByteArray() then native API store as a chunk. You could also store only the lower byte values if all the upper values are the same.  NB using many short methods per iteration or breakdown of process to small process segments is how RAM used gets marked quickly for GC dump in Java.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant `toByteArray()` creates a `byte[]` object which then has to be garbage-collected, which is specifically mentioned in the question as unwanted, and does not preserve the original UTF-16 format of the string, which is also mentioned in the question as an objective. I don't understand your final sentence.

Comment: @user207421
Thx your quick reply. CharBuffer.wrap() is an interesting approach, but there are two issues with it in this context:
This method itself creates a new CharBuffer object, which will introduce GC overhead.
Once I have the CharBuffer, it's challenging to bulk-copy data into the ByteBuffer. My ByteBuffer is a DirectByteBuffer allocated from JNI, so it can't be reallocated and must be used directly.

Comment: Well in that case `ByteBuffer.asCharBuffer().put(String)`, but note that it doesn't update `position` in the underlying `ByteBuffer`. This does create a new object however.

Comment: @user207421, I've checked the implementation of ByteBuffer.asCharBuffer().put(String) in JDK8, it calls "put(char)" for each character of String (gotten by charAt(int)) too.  lol, maybe put char one by one is the only way.

Comment: Well I certainly can't think of a better way: I'm really only trying to think of one-liners to save you having to write a loop and to increase the chance of HotSpot optimizations.

Comment: In recent Java versions, `java.lang.String` stores characters in a `byte[]` using either ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8, so there is no _"original UTF-16 format of the string"_.

Comment: I see Java does not have SIMD support until jdk 18.      https://vksegfault.github.io/posts/java-simd/

Comment: Read the API docs "Direct vs. non Direct buffers".         https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html.    Direct buffers operations use the underlying OS memory space.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it stores as either ISO-8859-1 or UTF-16 (native byte order), not UTF-8. But in principle, you are right, developers can not assume that the string has an “original UTF-16 format” and it’s not even clear why maintaining that format would be an actual goal when the receiving side is native code.